# Pseudocode: max of inversions

Tags: loops, max, permutation, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

I have the pseudocode:

[image]

If A have n random elements. If $n=64$, how many times can "the while loop" at most be run through by a call to $exists(A,n,x)$?. Is there a formula for that? But value for x and A[mid] have effect on the loops, how can I deal with it if I don't know the values?

Answer (score 1):

The worst case is when `x` is **not** in `A`, and the while loop needs to continue until lo=hi (instead of returning early when `x` is found).

In every iteration of the loop, the range checked is decreased by half, so at the worst case, it would run log<sub>2</sub>64 = 6 times.

As an exercise, you can assume `x` is smaller than any element in `A` and step through the program to confirm. Then repeat the exercise with the assumption that `x` is larger than any element of `A`.